# change email template before sending email

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, plugin

Guys am trying to modifying variables used in email templates, like store name, store email for every email.

How can we do this good manner?

Add plugin on \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface is good approach?

For example . : its in order_new.html

```
 {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
```

want to change store_name here

Comment: what do you mean by modifying variables?

Comment: for example we are showing contact at test@example.no, want to change this email

Answer (score 0):

What's displayed for store name and store email can be changed in the System-Configuration.

`Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Store Information -> Store Name` and `Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses -> General Contact -> Sender Name`

Comment: yeah I know about it but I want to change it programatically because I have more than 50 stores

Comment: and how exactly would changings tihs programatically faster?